# Calling an MVC Controller Action from a Javascript ajax function within an aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have a situation where I need to call an MVC controller action from a javascript file. However, the project is a WebForms project.

When running the request locally, everything works fine.

After it's deployed to a web server, it doesn't work.

You can see the image that I have where it works locally, but **not** on the web server.

I was somehow trying to make the action call using the Razor "@Url.Action" call, but it seems I can't put any Razor calls into the JS since it's not an MVC project.

I was trying another methodology with "<%= Html.Action", but got a server "Bad Request" with that.

How can I make this call successfully when deployed on a web server?

Here is the Controller I am trying to call.

```
public class ReversePenalizeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetReversePenalizeDataAsync()
```

Here is the JS Ajax call. Note that the commented out url line works fine locally, but gives me a "not found" on a web server. Note that the url line that is there now gives me a "bad request"

```
function getReversePenalizeData(parms)
{
    var serviceBase = '/ReversePenalize/'
    $.ajax({
        //url: serviceBase + 'GetReversePenalizeDataAsync',
        url: '<%= Html.Action("GetReversePenalizeDataAsync", "ReversePenalize") %>',
        data: JSON.stringify(parms),
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: true,
        success: function (data, textStatus)

        /// <returns>JsonResult - Grid data</returns>
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetReversePenalizeDataAsync()
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like your project can't load _any_ of the included files. Are you sure `../Scripts/etc` is correct?

Comment: we got this resolved by putting Page.ResolveUrl.